# Hibernate Validator (how to only accept a 4 letters and 10 digits)

Tags: java, regex, hibernate, hibernate-validator

I'm trying to validate a `String` with this format (4 letters and 10 digits):

> ABCD1234567890

But this code isn't working

```
@NotNull(message="tarjeta sanitaria cannot be null")
@Pattern(regexp = "(([A-Z]){4})([0-9]){10}",message = "tarjeta sanitaria is not valid")
private String tarjSanitaria;
```

Any idea?

Comment: In what way isn't the code working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you miss start and end of the string in your pattern.

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
^[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{10}$
```

You can test your regex using this page https://regex101.com/